# Show raw string data in html table

Tags: html, string

```
[id:protected] => 136845401 
[deviceId:protected] => 119648 
[message:protected] => The main message
[status:protected] => received 
[log:protected]
```

I am getting data from api in this format. I want to show these data in a html table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking a question, try to explain what you have attempted so far. As well as that, try to show us what your desired output is so we as answerers can better analyze your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with this

```js
const data = `[id:protected] => 136845401 
[deviceId:protected] => 119648 
[message:protected] => The main message
[status:protected] => received 
[log:protected]`
document.getElementById("tb").innerHTML = data.split(/\r?\n/).map(line => {
  const cells = line.split(" => ");
  return `<tr><td>${cells[0].replace(/[\[\]]/g,"").split(":")[0]}</td><td>${cells[1] || "&nbsp;"}</td></tr>`;
}).join("");
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tb"></tbody>
</table>
```